# Can't move my stream reader to the second column and add the years

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, listview, streamreader

I'm really new to visual studio c# I can't seem to add the text file (Stream reader) To my second column and add the years. I tried a few things but this is what I sort of came up with.  I tried doing the subitem add but it didn't work for me. I'm just going with what my teacher and the textbook showed but I haven't gotten much luck. The only real problem i'm having is having the stream reader show in the second column rather then the first as i need the first column to add the years.

edit. Sorry yeah whenever i try to type any code to move it to the second column in list view it either makes the txtfile disappear or it doesn't move at all.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    List<string> Populationsstats = new List<string>();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const int SIZE = 7;
        const int COLS = 2;
        string[] arrLines = new string[SIZE];
        int[] values = new int[COLS];
        double dblAverage;
        double dbllargest;
        double dblsmallets;

        listView1.GridLines = true;
        //listview default settings
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.FullRowSelect = true;

        //colum header
        listView1.Columns.Add("Year", 100);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Increase", 120);

        //declare a streamreader
        //StreamReader inputFile;
        StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText("USPopulation.txt");
        //open the file
        //   inputFile = File.OpenText("USPopulation.txt");

        //populate list
        while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            Populationsstats.Add(inputFile.ReadLine());
            // Populationsstats.Add(int.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine()));
        }

        //close file
        inputFile.Close();
        //show items on uspop txt
        //  listView1.Items.Clear();

        dblAverage = 2384;    //average equation
        listBox1.Items.Add("The Annual Change In Population:" + dblAverage.ToString());
        dbllargest = 1955;   //largest value
        listBox1.Items.Add("The Year with the Greatest Increase:" + dbllargest.ToString());
        dblsmallets = 1967; //Smallest value
        listBox1.Items.Add("The Year with the Least increase:" + dblsmallets.ToString());

        // show items in list view columns
        if (Populationsstats.Count != 0)
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < Populationsstats.Count; index++)
            {
                ListViewItem cols = new ListViewItem();
               listView1.Items.Add(Populationsstats[COLS].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to explain what “it didn't work” means. Is it showing an error? [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43300238/edit) your post to include the error. It's not giving you the answer you expect? What is it giving you? What did you expect? Your last sentence makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use

```
string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

And then get rows you need.